# Column with numbers for unique values

Tags: r, unique, dplyr

I have a tibble in R studio that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp50f.png) And I need to add a column that gives to each name the same unique number. So it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhkuy.png)

I have already tried things like the below code:

```
people >%>
gorup_by(Name) >%>
mutate(NameID = seq(1, along.with = unique(Name))) >%>
ungroup()
```

This code gave the same number for all the column. So it gave me a number 1 for every NameID.

I Also tried the below code:

```
people >%>
gorup_by(Name) >%>
mutate(NameID = seq(1, length(unique(Name)))) >%>
ungroup()
```

And I came with the same result. I think that I might need to use an `if function` or `ifelse`, but I really don't know what should be the correct syntax.

**sorry for the format, is my first time asking a question here and I need to learn to write things better**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` 1.0.0, we can use `cur_group_id`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Name = factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))) %>%
   mutate(NameID = cur_group_id())
```

---

Or without using `group_by`, it can be a `match`

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(NameID = match(Name, unique(Name)))
```

Or coerce the `factor` to `integer`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(NameID = as.integer(factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))))
```

Comment: Many thanks family. I have a feeling that I am gonna learn a lot thanks to people like you. It is really good to have this space. Thanks again!